# Advice for angular 2 plus file input and text input

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-http

please I have a form which contain text input and file input, and I can't really figure out the best approach to use, either to:

1. think towards uploading the file input as well as the text input in the same request.
2. make the file input a different component and make a separate request for the text input n file input

I need you to know at the back-end, I will need to store the uploaded file path and text input value in the database.

please what's the best advice I should go on with this. thanks